# Google Cloud Functions to only Ack Pub/Sub on success (Problem resolved by GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

An early version of Google Cloud Functions had a limitation with regards to retries when errors occurred.  They have since provided enhancements that resolve this issue.

---

We are using a cloud function triggered by Pub/Sub to ensure delivery of an e-mail.  Sometimes the e-mail service takes a long time to respond and our cloud function terminates before we get an error back.  Since the message has already been acknowledged our e-mail gets lost.

The cloud function appears to be sending an ACK the Pub/Sub message automatically when we are called.  Is there a way to delay the ACK until the successful completion of our code?  Alternatively is there a way to catch timeouts and requeue the message for delivery?  Something else we could try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem because Functions ACKing a message on invoke, even if they crash, prevents the use of the new "dead-letter" feature.

Also, it goes against the docs. see note after this code sample:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#sample_code

Comment: It looks like Google has added some retry support since this question was asked three years ago.  I agree with you that the answer has changed.

Answer (score 18):

I heard from Google support that they do not currently provide the means to delay the ACK when a cloud function is invoked by Pub/Sub.  If you want to use cloud functions with Pub/Sub you need to handle the error case yourself.  For example you could have your cloud function requeue a message for the retry with a retry count.

This would seem to make it unnecessarily difficult to guarantee execution with Pub/Sub and cloud functions.

Comment: this was a terrible design decision.  They should have left it up to the cloud function to ack the message.

Comment: Or perhaps only ack'd it when the function finished successfully.

Comment: Any best practices on how to overcome this? I thought about using a timer and posting the same message to the topic again. Anything better?

Comment: Any update on this? For the time being I have instead been using a HTTP trigger where I can ack the message myself with a 2xx response but it feels like it's an unnecessary workaround.

Comment: There is another way by setting `--retry` on the trigger function. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries

Comment: That's a much less useful way though; pubsub topics support backoff, function retries are immediate.

Comment: This is very very big limitation...