# Google Pubsub subscriber that does a http PUSH to a cloud function (in same project or another project)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to setup a pubsub topic/subscriber in one project that does a http PUSH to a cloud function in the same OR in another google project? I know there are PubSub triggers but these do not work when the pubsub topic is in another google project. Curious if this even doable with a subscriber PUSH.

Error I get thiis pubsub error INVALID_ARGUMENT if I try to create it. I wasn't sure if this was because I needed to register the endpoint (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#other-endpoints). However that didn't feel right because when I create a function, the URL is given to me automatically and I can hit it via Postman.

I did find this link ([GCP - Verify ownership of a cloud function https endpoint for a PubSub push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920403/gcp-verify-ownership-of-a-cloud-function-https-endpoint-for-a-pubsub-push)) and think it is url-verification related.. just want a confirmation :)

Thoughts? Did I miss some documentation somewhere?

**EDIT**: I think it's related to URL verification as well as using the `../_ah/push-handlers/..` path. When I register a PubSub trigger, the delivery type to the function is still a PUSH but it's to a encoded url with more of a path: `https://{hash}-dot-{hash}.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/{project-id}/topics/prototype-contact-created?pubsub_trigger=true`

Comment: The control panel shows only INVALID_ARGUMENT but if you use the gcloud command-line tool you'll get an error "The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project (`url="https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/testPubSub/test-pubsub", project_id="<pid>").`" so this error is because of unverified endpoints.

Answer (score 5):

This was a solution I was given here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/118

> You need to verify this URL by going on your Google Cloud Console, `API
>   & Services`, `Credentials`, then the `Domain Verification` tab. Add the url
>   of your Cloud Functions. You will need to do that for each and every
>   one.
>
> Then, make sure that in the Search Console, you select the META TAG
>   verification method, and response with that on `GET` requests.

```
if (req.method === 'GET') {
      // mine is in a settings file but you can hardcode yours for testing purposes
      return res.send(`<html><head><meta name="google-site-verification" content="${settings.google.siteVerificationCode}" /></head><body></body></html>`)
}
```