# Cloud Function to retrieve attributes from PubSub - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a GCP Cloud Functions which is triggered by a PubSub topic.

```
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

I publish messages using the below command which triggers the Cloud Functions.

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish test-topic --message="test" \
  --attribute="origin=gcloud-sample,username=gcp"
```

Using this I can access only the "message" part of the topic. How can I access the "attribute" values from the PubSub message. I want to fetch the origin and username from the topic.

Comment: Hi @Ashok KS, did the below answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation for v1 Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub-1st-gen#functions_helloworld_pubsub_tutorial-python):

```py
"""
event (dict):  The dictionary with data specific to this type of
                event. The `@type` field maps to
                 `type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage`.
                The `data` field maps to the PubsubMessage data
                in a base64-encoded string. The `attributes` field maps
                to the PubsubMessage attributes if any is present.
"""
```

So I think just using `event['attributes']` should work. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025107/consume-pubsub-in-google-cloud-function).